# TypeScript failed to set initial state for reducer

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I got the following error while setting one of the `reuder`,

```
/Users/Lxinyang/Desktop/angular/breakdown/ui/app/src/reducers/filters.spec.ts
(12,9): error TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ selectionState: { source: string; timeRange: Date[]; }; } | undefined'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type '{ selectionState: { source: string; timeRange: Date[]; }; }'.
    Property 'selectionState' is missing in type '{}'.
```

The code for the reducer,

```
const DATE_IN_MILLISECONDS = 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000
const todayDate = new Date()
const startDate = new Date(todayDate.getTime() - 6 * DATE_IN_MILLISECONDS)
const defaultFiltersState = {
  selectionState: { source: 'all', timeRange: [startDate, todayDate] }
}

export function filters(state = defaultFiltersState, action: any) {}
```

I'm not sure why I am having this issue because I never assign `{}` to the default state.

Code below is the root,

```
export default combineReducers({ dataSource, filters, filtersVideo })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is I set an empty `{}` state while creating the store,

```
const configureStore = (initialState: any) => {
  return createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk))
}
```

When app init,

```
const store = configureStore({})
```